# Is there any way to use one html file for one screen-width, and another at another screen-width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It will be easier for me to use these 2 separate html files than to rearrange my code. I thought about using a media-query, or jquery but I realized that this would not be possible. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in a case like you mentioned I would build the pages on the fly, but not sure what tech you are using there is no tag for the tech in your post.

It is possible to do this with jQuery. I have used this in the past.

Here is a function that will load one of two HTML files to a DIV based on screen width.

```
$(function() 
{   
     var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
     if (screenWidth > 1024) {   
       loadDIV("file1.html");
     }
     else
     {
        loadDIV("file2.html");
     }
}); 

function loadDIV(fileName)
{
    $.get( fileName, function( data ) { 
        $( "#Content" ).html( data );  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What are the drawbacks of doing something like this? Does it take a lot of time to load an html page?

Comment: George this is a concept that is used in a Single Page App (SPA) or Partial Views in a .NET MVC App.  Once your page loads and jQuery Read fires it grabs the HTML it would be like pulling an external JavaScript or CSS file from the server. Take a look at this simple demo on my blog, (then click the demo link) it loads the content very fast that it appears it is in one request... http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2016/11/17/load-content-to-html-page-from-an-external-file... I have a friend that does this for many pages on his Wordpress Site.